# Handsontable Infinite Scroll Append Data and apply Merge Cells Formatting

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm working with handsontable and want to append data with an infinite scroll. I can achieve this with a simplified example using:

> Array.prototype.push.apply

I expected to find a handsontable method that would allow me to append data, however I have searched and searched and found nothing. Perhaps I'm missing something and if so I'd really appreciate any direction you can offer.

Here is my simplified infinite scroll example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data = [
    ["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
    ["2000", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2001", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2002", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2003", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2004", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2005", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2006", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2007", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2008", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2010", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2011", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2012", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2013", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2014", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2015", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
  ];
  var moreData = [
    ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 14, 10],
    ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13, 25],
    ["2019", 20, 11, 14, 14, 10],
    ["2020", 30, 15, 12, 13, 25]
  ];
  var $container2 = $("#HoT2");

  $container2.handsontable({
      data: data,
      colHeaders: true,
      contextMenu: true,
  });
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      appendHOT2();
    }
  }); 

  function appendHOT2() {
//    rowCount = $container2.handsontable('countRows'); console.log("Row Count: "+rowCount);
//    $container2.handsontable('alter', 'insert_row', rowCount, 3); // Add set number of empty rows

    var hotData = $container2.handsontable('getData');
    Array.prototype.push.apply(hotData, moreData);
    console.log("Array: "+ hotData);
    $container2.handsontable('loadData', hotData); //Replaces current data doesn't append
  }
});
```

```css
</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue --><script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com//bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.com/demo/css/samples.css">
```

```html
<h2>Infinite Scroll - Simple Load More Rows</h2>
<div id="HoT2" class="handsontable"></div>
```

In reality I want to do something more complex with object data (from an ajax call), but I don't know how to update handsontable with the data and formatting.

Here's my example as far as I've taken it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var colHeaders = [
  'ID','Name','Address'
  ];
  var mergeCells = [
    {row:0, col:0, rowspan:2, colspan:1},
    {row:0, col:1, rowspan:2, colspan:1},
    {row:0, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:2, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:2, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:2, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:3, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:3, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:3, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:4, col:0, rowspan:2, colspan:1},
    {row:4, col:1, rowspan:2, colspan:1},
    {row:4, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:5, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:5, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:5, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:6, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:6, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:6, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
  ];
  var data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Ted Right', address: 'A1'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Ted Right', address: 'A2'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Frank Honest', address: 'B'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Joan Well', address: 'C'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Gail Polite', address: 'D1'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Gail Polite', address: 'D2'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Michael Fair', address: 'E'},
  ];
  var moreData = [
      {id: 6, name: 'Ted 2Right', address: 'F'},
      {id: 7, name: 'Frank 2Honest', address: 'G1'},
      {id: 7, name: 'Frank 2Honest', address: 'G2'},
      {id: 8, name: 'Joan 2Well', address: 'H'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Gail 2Polite', address: 'I1'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Gail 2Polite', address: 'I2'},
      {id: 9, name: 'Gail 2Polite', address: 'I3'},
      {id: 10, name: 'Michael 2Fair', address: 'J'},
  ];
  var moreMergeCells = [
    {row:7, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:7, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:7, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:8, col:0, rowspan:2, colspan:1},
    {row:8, col:1, rowspan:2, colspan:1},
    {row:8, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:9, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:9, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:9, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:10, col:0, rowspan:3, colspan:1},
    {row:10, col:1, rowspan:3, colspan:1},
    {row:10, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:11, col:0, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:11, col:1, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
    {row:11, col:2, rowspan:1, colspan:1},
  ];
  var $container = $("#HoT2");

  $container.handsontable({
      data: data,
      colHeaders: colHeaders,
      mergeCells: mergeCells,
      contextMenu: false,
  });
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      appendHOT2();
    }
  }); 

  function appendHOT2() {
    console.log("Append Data and MergeCells...");
    
// Append moreData and moreMergeCells data to the handsontable display 
// How can this be achieved?
  }
});
```

```css
</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue --> <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com//bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.com/demo/css/samples.css">
```

```html
<h2>Infinite Scroll - Load More Formatted Rows</h2>
<div id="HoT2" class="handsontable"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically what you're looking for is 
`$container.handsontable('updateSettings', ({mergeCells: newMergeCells}));`
but I strongly advise you to code a more generic function if you want to modify the settings of your table when scrolling. For example a function that detect the cells to be merged according to your new data. Then you can use the updateSettings function with much less danger of having strong discrepencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, if you want to update the settings of your table when scrolling (ref: updating the mergeCells setting), a more generic function is, IMO, mandatory... At least, much simpler :)

This line is what you need to do every time you scroll :

```
$container.handsontable('updateSettings', ({mergeCells: merge()}));
```

(you will note that I used it once after the initialisation of the table).

---

See the function below which, based on the structure of your data in your example, merge the columns 1 and 2 if the value of the column 1 repeat itself :

```
function merge() {
  var mergeCells=[], rowspan=1, tempName = '';

  for(var i=0; i<$container.handsontable('getData').length;i++) {
    if ($container.handsontable('getDataAtCell', i,1) === tempName) {
      rowspan+=1;
    } 
    else  {
      mergeCells.push({row:i-rowspan, col:0, rowspan:rowspan, colspan:1})
      mergeCells.push({row:i-rowspan, col:1, rowspan:rowspan, colspan:1})
      rowspan=1
    }
    tempName = $container.handsontable('getDataAtCell', i,1);
  }
  return mergeCells;
}
```

You can find the complete and working example in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kh1jc6m6/).

Comment: Thanks Fap. Your initial comment lead me in the right direction. I ended up using JQuery merge to merge my data, which were arrays of objects e.g. `mergeData = $.merge(data,moreData);`